# OpenGL: auto-generating mipmaps only for certain layers of a 2D texture array

Tags: arrays, opengl, graphics

I have a big texture array with images (a few hundred) for a big batched together mesh. I now need to update certain "slices" or layers of that array frequently.

My problem is that when using `glGenerateMipmap()` the driver seems to recreate the mipmaps for **ALL layers** of that texture array instead of just the updated ones. Is there a way to just update one layer and recreate its mipmap without recreating the mipmaps for all the layers at the same time?

What I currently do when I update a slice/layer of the 2D texture array:

```
glTexSubImage3D(EXTTextureArray.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT,
        0, //mipmap level
        0,
        0,
        sliceIndex,
        width,
        height,
        1,
        glFormat,
        GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        currentData);

glGenerateMipmap(EXTTextureArray.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT);
```

When I ommit the `glGenerateMipmap()` then the mipmaps are not update at all. So is there a way to auto create the mipmaps only for that layer or do I need to create the mipmaps myself in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `glGenerateMipmap` will always re-create all mipmap levels from `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL+1` to `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL`. In case of a 2D array texture, this means it will work on all layers of said texture.

> Is there a way to just update one layer and recreate its mipmap without recreating the mipmaps for all the layers at the same time?

In modern GL (>=4.3), you might be able to achieve this via [texture views](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_views). Basically, you can create a new 2D texture object which is just a *view* of a single layer of your array texture with [`glTextureVIew`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTextureView.xhtml), and re-generate mipmaps for that one. However, for that to work, you must create your array texture as [*immutable*](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Immutable_storage) via [`glTexStorage3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage3D.xhtml).

Comment: You confirmed what I feared - `glGenerateMipmap` is an all or nothing method. But thank you giving a pure OpenGL solution - I'll definitely test it. For now I solved it by creating the mipmap levels myself and uploading it via `glTexSubImage3D()`. To not introduce a lag I put the mipmap generation into an extra thread (upload of course in the main thread) - works like a charm. But I guess glGenerateMipmap uses the GPU to do the filtering, so might be better to use your solution after all.

Comment: Well, you can also create the mipmap levels manually, via via render to texture, or a compute shader.